# How to combine an AnimationDrawable with another animation?

Tags: android, jquery-animate, animationdrawable

Is it possible to combine these 2 animations below? It works but it seems weird to have to call them separately ( 2 calls to start() )

```
    ImageView rocketImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rocket_image);
    rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rocket_thrust);
    rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();

    rocketImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        rocketAnimation.start();
        rocketImage.animate().x(100).y(100).withLayer().setDuration(500).start();
      }
  });
```

Comment: What is your actual requirement?

Comment: the requirement is to run both animations. For most animations, we can use the AnimatorSet to combine several, but I can't figure out how to add an AnimationDrawable to AnimatorSet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [AnimatorSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html) and use the function `playTogether`. However, as you mentioned in your comments, `AnimationDrawable` is not compatible with `AnimatorSet`. In this case, to ensure both animations start together, you can write it like this

```
AnimationDrawable rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();

rocketImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    rocketImage.animate().x(100).y(100).withLayer().setDuration(500).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            rocketAnimation.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    }).start();
  }
```

});

Comment: ok, then write down the code please? because when I tried to add the AnimationDrawable to AnimatorSet, it's says it's incompatible with Animator